# How to figure out exactly URI of my network printer(Canon MX358)?

Tags: network-printer, bonjour, broadcast, lpr, uri

I have successfully setup my printer(Canon PIXMA MX358) as a network printer, and connected/configured it correctly in Kubuntu 20.04, if my computer lived in the same LAN (same broadcast-domain) of the printer.

But the printing service cannot be used when the computer is moved into another WLAN(another broadcast-domain), although the printer can be pinged on the computer(I know the ip address of the printer).

I want to let all the subnets of my home can use this printing service.
There is no NAT between all of these subnets.

My printer's default service URI looks like `dnssd://MX358_XXXXXXXXXXXX._printer._tcp.local/`, but it works only for the same LAN as the printer lives.

Is there a way to compose a exact URI by replacing the logical name in the default URI with the real IP and port number and some queue name?

I'm not familiar with Bonjour protocol, I guess that my PC can discover the printing-service because of some broadcasting mechanism, so it cannot be done in a different broadcast area of Ethernet.

How should I figure out the correct protocol and port number? And then what should I append to a URI likes `lpr://192.168.x.x:631/`?

So that I can enjoy printing-service anywhere.

Thanks for any hints.
Pls forgive my poor English.

Comment: If you set a static IP / assign it in the router based on MAC address, you can then reach the printers without things like bonjour.  The likelihood us you can print with lpr/port 9100 - but of-course this is printer specific.

Comment: @davidgo thanks! I have already used static IP for the printer, I just don't know which printing protocol(such as lpr or ipp) and what port number it supports. In other words, I don't know how to translate the URI of Bonjour to the URI of IPP that use direct IP instead of logical name.

Comment: You should add the model of your printer to the question.  (I note I've never had a prptocol ssue setting up HP, OKI and Brother printers - normally if I log in to the printer web Interfaces it gives me hints. Also, as 631 and 9100 are both TCP I can always telnet to the printers to see if the appropriate port is open.

Comment: Ive never played with bonjure, but I'm 99% certain you can replace MX358...local with an IP address.

Comment: @davidgo The model is "Canon PIXMA MX358", I updated the question. Thank you again!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, after many times trying.

When we open the dialog box "Add a New Printer", the corresponding hint would NOT appear in the window, and it would try to find out the net printer automatically(certainly we know that it will get failed since we live a different sub-net with the printer).

After the dialog box stopped to find printer, we click a entry other than "Manual URI" in the list at the left area of the window, and then select "Manual URI" again, so that let the dialog-box refresh/repaint the right area of the window.

Now, the hint would appear in the right area of the window. At the bottom right area, there is a link "***See "Network Printers" for the correct URI to use with your printer.***". After hitting it, a browser window would be open, and it would show us many hints about how to manually compose the URI to the printer.

According to the hints, I composed successfully the URI of my printer finally.
It looks like `lpd://192.168.x.x/queue`.

Hope this post can help somebody in the futures.
Done.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the answer in the Canon article
[Understand Security and Firewall Settings - MAXIFY, PIXMA, TR Series](https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART109227):

[image]